# Decimal field format in ASP.NETCore model

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model

In SQL Server I have a primary key of a Table declared as follow :

```
[CustomerID] [numeric](18, 0) IDENTITY(1000000,1) NOT NULL,
```

In ASP.NET Core 2.2 model i mapped this field ad follow :

```
public decimal CustomerId { get; set; }
```

How can I make the decimal digits not appear in the application?

Comment: When you have a decimal value there is always the decimal digits in it, you have to format it before displaying. basically the representation of that value can be changed according to the formatting.

Comment: @Siavash : It isn't possible to do something with annotations?

Comment: of course, it is, that formatting can take place anywhere. I see there is already an answer using annotations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use DisplayFormat attribute:

```cs
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:0}", ApplyFormatInEditMode =true)]
public decimal CustomerId { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to display it without decimal places, then the formatting can be applied with a `ToString` anywhere, preferably where you are trying to display it. The code below will apply rounding.

```
CustomerId.ToString("0");
```

If you need to use it in some other capacity without the decimal points then you should map your model representing the database table to another model specific to what you are trying to do and supply the correct type in that model. Probably an `int` or `string` in this case.